# Почему в браузере не отображается модель сделанная в 3ds Max?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, 3dsmax

Мне предоставили 3D модель сделанную в 3ds Max и конвертировали её в формат .dae. Я использую Three.js для работы с 3д графикой, для загрузки модели делаю следующее

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    /*loader.load( 'model/stormtrooper.dae', function ( collada ) {*/
    loader.load( 'model/test.dae', function ( collada ) {
        console.log(collada);
        var animations = collada.animations;
        avatar = collada.scene;
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( avatar );
        //var action = mixer.clipAction( animations[ 0 ] ).play();
        scene.add( avatar );
    } );
```

В консоли я вижу, что то есть, но оно не отображается.
В моём коде есть закоментированная строка, где подключается модель stormtrooper.dae - это с примера, который я взял на официальном сайте. Если я использую другие модели в формате .dae, взятые на просторах сети они также запускаются без проблем. Очевидно, что проблема в модели, которую мне предоставили. Может кто знает как правильно конвертировать с 3ds Max в .dae, что бы оно загрузилось через `THREE.ColladaLoader();`

Comment: Можно с этой моделью (если она не супер-секретная) забежать на [форум](https://discourse.threejs.org/). Там специалисты подскажут.

Comment: @Air редактирование моделей и поиск проблем в них у нас все равно оффтопик, так предлагаю оставить ссылку

Comment: @PashaPash, ok...

Comment: @prisoner849, ты выиграл... )))

Comment: @Air Да у нас тут не состязание :) Выигрыш или проигрыш через полезность или бесполезность информации в комментариях/ответах - это больше для автора вопроса.

Comment: @detriat я тут подумал еще об одном: масштаб модели. Может получиться так, что камера находится внутри нее и модель поэтому не видна. Опять же - все зависит от модели и ее сложности.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылки имеют не полный вид `model/test.dae` попробуйте их прописать с http или https с доменом

Comment: С ссылками там все в порядке. Автор пишет, что _"В консоли я вижу, что то есть, но оно не отображается"_ (судя по всему, это результат вызова `console.log(collada);`). Видимо, что-то не так с экспортированной моделью.Причин - масса: неправильные параметры экспорта, неправильная работа экспортера, баг в загрузчике и т.д, и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось очень просто! Мне должны были предоставить модель, по примеру, которая запускалась без дополнительных усердий. Но видимо с моделью что то было не так. Решением проблемы стало наложение материала на модели вручную и всё заработало. Всем спасибо за ответы

Comment: Звучит интригующе :) Какой материал был на модели изначально? Какой материал применяли вручную?

Comment: Я не знаю, какой был материал изначально :( Я вручную наложил BasicMaterial + так же наложил текстуру. Это было сделано для теста. Вообще нужно было наложить материал кожи как здесь https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_skin.html